# Como usar If Else corretamente

Tags: javascript, if

Tenho os seguintes *checkboxes*:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check"  id="livros" value="livros"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="folhas" value="folhas"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="porta" value="porta"/>

 <a href="#" class="botao" onclick="Avaliar_checkbox()">Avaliar</a>
```

e preciso compará-los de acordo com o que o usuário escolher:

```
function Avaliar_checkbox() {

    // Variáveis 
     var livros = document.getElementById("livros");
     var folhas = document.getElementById("folhas");
     var porta = document.getElementById("porta");


// Variáveis 
if (livros.checked) {
        alert('livros');
     }
if (folhas.checked) {
        alert('folhas');
     }
if (porta.checked) {
        alert('porta');
     }
if (livros.checked && porta.checked) {
        alert('Livros e Porta');
     }
if (livros.checked && folhas.checked && porta.checked) {
        alert('Livros, folhas e porta');
     }
}
```

O problema é que quando executo a função, as condições entram em conflito, me retornam dois resultados ou não retornam nada. Qual seria a maneira correta de fazer isso?

Comment: Eu daria uma olhada em switch-case, que apesar de ser um pouco mais lento ajuda muito na legibilidade do código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acho que é isto que deseja. Se cada opção é mutualmente exclusive precisa elas precisam ser avaliadas como uma estrutura só, executando uma delas, não executa as outras seguintes. Isto de fato é obtido com o `else`.

Mas também precisa colocar as opções mais restritivas na frente. Ou seja, a opção que precisa ter mais condições verdadeiras deve vir antes que as outras mais simples. Se não fizer isto a que tem apenas uma opção executa e se outras opções foram ligadas não serão executadas.

Não sei se era a intenção ou esqueceu que existem outras possibilidades de combinações de ter dois *checkboxes* ligados.

```js
function Avaliar_checkbox() {
    var livros = document.getElementById("livros");
    var folhas = document.getElementById("folhas");
    var porta = document.getElementById("porta");
    if (livros.checked && folhas.checked && porta.checked) alert('Livros, folhas e porta');
    else if (livros.checked && porta.checked) alert('Livros e Porta');
    else if (livros.checked) alert('livros');
    else if (folhas.checked) alert('folhas');
    else if (porta.checked) alert('porta');
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="check"  id="livros" value="livros"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="folhas" value="folhas"/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="porta" value="porta"/>

<a href="#" class="botao" onclick="Avaliar_checkbox()">Avaliar</a>
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Syntax/ElseIf.js).

Answer (score 4):

Você está fazendo a comparação de maneira incorreta, para o seu caso eu aconselho utilizar `if-else` assim:

```
if (livros.checked && folhas.checked && porta.checked) {
    alert('Livros, folhas e porta');
} else if (livros.checked && porta.checked) {
    alert('Livros e Porta');
} else if (livros.checked) {
    alert('livros');
} else if (folhas.checked) {
    alert('folhas');
} else if (porta.checked) {
    alert('porta');
}
```

Primeiro você verifica livros, folhas e porta, se ambos estiverem checados, ele dá o `alert("Livros, folhas e porta")`, senão e se livros e porta estiverem checados ele manda o `alert`, e assim por diante, repare no uso do `else` antes do `if`, é ele que vai fazer com que a próxima verificação seja chamada, mas somente se a anterior falhar, dessa forma você não executa o `alert` mais do que o necessário.