# Como dimunuir a quantidade de if / else if?

Tags: javascript

Olá! Estou aprendendo a usar o `if/else`. Vi algumas explicações nos fóruns e alguns vídeos, mas não estou conseguindo eliminar a quantidade enorme de `if/else if` na função e desejo saber a forma recomendada/comum de realizar essa eliminação no meu caso. Removi algumas linhas para facilitar a compreensão. Primeiro passa pela verificação de `idade.value` e depois `classificacao` recebe a mensagem de acordo o valor do `valorIMC` e no final retorna `classficacao`. O cálculo do IMC foi feito em outra função e o valor armazenado em `valorIMC`.

```js
function imcMasculino(idade){
  let classificacao = '';
  if (idade.value < 14){
    if(valorIMC < 18){
      classificacao = 'desnutrição grau I';
    }else if(valorIMC < 23){
      classificacao = 'normal';
    }else if(valorIMC < 28){
      classificacao = 'pré-obesidade';
    }else if(valorIMC > 28.01){
      classificacao = 'obesidade grau I';
    }
  }else if(idade.value < 24){
    if(valorIMC < 19){
      classificacao = 'desnutrição grau I';
    }else if(valorIMC < 24){
      classificacao = 'normal';
    }else if(valorIMC < 29){
      classificacao = 'pré-obesidade';
    }else if(valorIMC > 29.01){
      classificacao = 'obesidade grau I';
    }
  }else if(idade.value < 34){
    if(valorIMC < 16){
      classificacao = 'desnutrição grau II';
    }else if(valorIMC < 20){
      classificacao = 'desnutrição grau I';
    }else if(valorIMC < 25){
      classificacao = 'normal';
    }else if(valorIMC < 30){
      classificacao = 'pré-obesidade';
    }else if(valorIMC > 30.01){
      classificacao = 'obesidade grau I';
    }
  }
  return classificacao;
}
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4907/como-funciona-este-if-else-com-e?rq=1 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/185525/como-usar-if-else-corretamente?rq=1 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/514784/como-diminuir-a-quantidade-de-if-else-para-a-mesma-valida%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-diferentes-propr?rq=1

Comment: Pode fazer um array e um for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sempre que vocês está manualmente repetindo o seu código é porque dá pra subistituir por um `for`, simples assim.

---

Uma das formas, talvez a mais simples que consigo pensar seria:

```
let _imcRules = {
    14: [0, 18, 23, 28],
    24: [0, 19, 24, 29],
    34: [16, 20, 25, 30],
}

let _imcText = ["desnutrição grau II", "desnutrição grau I", "normal", "pré-obesidade", "obesidade grau I"];
```

Dessa forma você tem um array que descreve quais são as idades minimas e depois o IMC minimo para cada um (exceto obesidade grau 1, já que esse é apenas se for maior do que os demais, então é a condição padrão).

---

No final ficaria algo como:

```
let _imcRules = {
    14: [0, 18, 23, 28],
    24: [0, 19, 24, 29],
    34: [16, 20, 25, 30],
}

let _imcText = ["desnutrição grau II", "desnutrição grau I", "normal", "pré-obesidade", "obesidade grau I"];

function imcMasculino(idade, imc) {  
  let m = Object.keys(_imcRules)
  for (let k = 0; k < m.length; k++) { 
    if (idade > m[k]) { continue; }
    
    let v = _imcRules[m[k]];
    for (let t = 0; t < v.length; t++ ) {
      if (imc < v[t]) { return _imcText[t]; }
    }
  }
  return _imcText[_imcText.length-1];
}
```

Você provavelmente poderia usar outras funções nativas do JS para simplificar o código, como `Map` ou `Each`. Mas, preferi não utilizar para deixar mais claro a ideia, de forma que possa ser feita independente da linguagem.